# "Ridgy didge" — what's that mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, slang, australian-english

Australia day is nearly upon us! And that means it's time to throw another steak on the barbie and say *real* Aussie things like "ridgy didge".

Flaming heck, what's that even mean, "ridgy didge"? I've been saying it for years in sentences like,

> I'm true blue, fair dinkum, ridgy didge, dinky die Aussie.

Does anyone know what "ridgy didge" means and where it came from?

Answer (score 3):

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ridgy-didge) says

> ***ridgy didge***, fanciful diminutive of obsolete ridge (“real; used in reference to gold”).
>    Australian, colloquial from 1953.
>
> Sense 1: Genuine, authentic, true; honest, upright.
>   *Are you ridgy-didge? - Do you really mean that? Are you telling the truth?*
>
> Sense 2: Good, fine.

---

Regarding that obsolete usage, OED says

> ***ridge***, n.2 Cant. Now only U.S. [Origin obscure.]   Gold; gold coin. Also, any metal coin.
>   *ridge-cully*, a goldsmith.

I doubt the *didge* part means anything at call - it's just [reduplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication) (repetitive alliteration) along the lines of *Okey-dokey, higgledy-piggledy*, etc.